# How to Deploy a "create-react-app" based app on jetty/tomcat

Tags: node.js, maven, tomcat, npm, jetty

I am trying to deploy a react based app in **jetty**. As part of that, I thought of trying to do the same in jetty server.
I followed a link:
https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/

The above link explains details about it and at the end there is a github project for making a war. the link to that is below:
https://github.com/megadix/create-react-app-servlet

Now, I am able to deploy the war created using the above github project in tomcat 9. I am **unable** to understand how the dependency resolution of node_modules is happening. Also I am **unable** to deploy the same war in jetty(putting the war in webapps folder and starting jetty)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Single page applications needs to be compiled into one (in same cases more) .js file. In your case, create-react-app or similar tools are responsible for fulfilling this requirement.

In the pom.xml execution list, you can see npm install, npm build commands. They are pretty much similar as mvn clean install and mvn buuild.

Dependencies are resolved from package.json dependencies field and installed under node_modules. Once dependencies are there, npm build (or create-react-app-servlet build), compiles all the source code + dependencies into a js file. This probably has a name like main.XXXXXX.js.

In the end, you have a dist folder consisting of .html, .js and other resources.

It'd be better if you share more details of what's happening with jetty deployment

Comment: Thanks. When I try to deploy the war on jetty(copying the war in webapps and starting jetty). On opening "localhost:8080/my-app", I get 404.

Comment: Also, In your above comment, when I host it the war on tomcat. How does tomcat know about the node_modules. I mean I don't see any node_modules under tomcat's "webapps/my-app/*".

Comment: The 404 error on jetty seems really weird to me. Both war directories should have an index.html file and that should be opened by default. Maybe your jetty server doesn't open index.html files by default? You can try localhost:8080/my-app/index.html.       There shouldn't be any node_modules under my-app. As I said, when you run the build task, all the source code plus the javascript code needed from node_modules compiled into main.js file. Once it's in main.js, you don't need node_modules anymore

Comment: Thanks for the main.js explanation. I get 404 with localhost:8080/my-app/index.html also